# Check for conflicts in tracked files using Git command line

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Is there a Git command at the command line that can check for existing conflicts in tracked files?

Essentially it would be search for those

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

character sequences...I usually do that manually :)

but surely there must be some tool that can search and report those?

Comment: Try a merge tool (e.g. Meld) to [resolve conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git).

Comment: git grep?   But how are files getting checked in with conflict markers in the first place?

Comment: Try `git diff --check`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git status` that will tell you which files are in conflict state. As stated in the comments, you can use a merge tool. If you don't want to, you can still do `git checkout --ours` and perform a `git diff` to get the difference the "diff" way. The latter can be customized with `git difftool` (Cf. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html)